# PayPal not able to complete a transaction

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal, e-commerce

I'm trying to complete a transaction with PayPal, its sets the transaction as it should and I'm getting through the checkout flow just as usual. But after that nothing happens. literally nothing. the form closes and no alert is coming through.
Here is my code:
This is my blade view.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<body>
    <p>{{ $course->title }}</p>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>


</body>    
@endsection

@section('scripts') 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ') }}"></script> 
    <script defer src="{{asset('/js/loadPaypal.js')}}"></script>
@endsection

@yield('scripts')
```

And this is the JS file:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
})

paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '1000000'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Here are the console errors:
1.

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <style>, as they will not be parsed.

41 |              
42 |      <p>HTML noobies</p>
43 |      <div id="paypal-button-container"><div id="zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm" class="paypal-buttons paypal-buttons-context-iframe paypal-buttons-label-undefined paypal-buttons-layout-vertical" style="height: 168px;"><style>
   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^^^^^^^
44 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
45 |                          position: relative;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
46 |                          display: inline-block;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
47 |                          width: 100%;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
48 |                          min-height: 35px;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
49 |                          min-width: 200px;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
50 |                          max-width: 750px;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
51 |                          font-size: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
52 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
53 |  
   |  
54 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > iframe {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
55 |                          position: absolute;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
56 |                          top: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
57 |                          left: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
58 |                          width: 100%;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
59 |                          height: 100%;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
60 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
61 |  
   |  
62 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > iframe.component-frame {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
63 |                          z-index: 100;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
64 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
65 |  
   |  
66 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > iframe.prerender-frame {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67 |                          transition: opacity .2s linear;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
68 |                          z-index: 200;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
69 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
70 |  
   |  
71 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > iframe.visible {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
72 |                          opacity: 1;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
73 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
74 |  
   |  
75 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > iframe.invisible {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
76 |                          opacity: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
77 |                          pointer-events: none;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
78 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
79 |  
   |  
80 |                      #zoid-paypal-buttons-15c9e8f973_mtg6mje6mjm > .smart-menu {
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
81 |                          position: absolute;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
82 |                          z-index: 300;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
83 |                          top: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
84 |                          left: 0;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
85 |                          width: 100%;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
86 |                      }
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
87 |                  </style><iframe allowtransparency="true" name="__zoid__paypal_buttons__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__" title="paypal" allowpaymentrequest="allowpaymentrequest" scrolling="no" id="jsx-iframe-47f585f579" class="component-frame invisible" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;"></iframe><iframe allowtransparency="true" name="__zoid_prerender_frame__paypal_buttons_a51937771f_mtg6mje6mjm__" title="paypal" allowpaymentrequest="allowpaymentrequest" scrolling="no" id="jsx-iframe-7e9201988f" class="prerender-frame visible" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;"></iframe><div id="smart-menu" class="smart-menu"></div></div></div>

88 |      
   |  ^^^^
89 |  
   |  
90 |      
   |  ^^^^
91 |          </main>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
92 |      </div>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

error 2:

```
unhandled_error Here is my paypal id {err: "Error: Window closed↵    at https://www.paypal.com…EwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2:8425", timestamp: "1591899685628", referer: "127.0.0.1:8000", uid: "445e7a01e2_mtg6mtu6mjq", env: "sandbox"}
```

error 3:

```
Uncaught Error: Window closed
    at js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
    at e.n.dispatch (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at e.n.then (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at Ce (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
    at e.n.dispatch (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at e.n.resolve (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at e.n.dispatch (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at e.n.resolve (js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2)
    at js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.then @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
Ce @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.resolve @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.resolve @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
setTimeout (async)
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.reject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.asyncReject @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.then @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
ve @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.then @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
Ce @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.resolve @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.resolve @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
e @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
e.delay @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
e @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.then @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
e.try @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
render @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.dispatch @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
n.then @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
r @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
render @ js?client-id=AYJIx-sjImWmpIBdQ1hi8g9b7_il4T2AlGcVprEwDxdsjolQnxICqAEAHnQNkAGGr8HlGoLg0MBbMhrJ:2
(anonymous) @ loadPaypal.js:23
Show 16 more frames
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the capture simply isn't successful. Have you tried adding an alert() or other logging to the onApprove() function ?

Try testing with a more reasonable amount than `1000000`, such as `100`

Comment: just realized it didn't even set up the purchase, because in the pop up it show 0.1$, but I set it to 10$.

Comment: Hey,@Preston, i fixed this by simply changing <script type=text/javascript> to <script type=application/javascript> thank you very much for you time!